# Import XML into SQL Server, split into multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a XML file, which I need to import into a SQL Server database. The XML file is build like this:

```
<report>
  <deltagere>
    <deltager>
    <number>142555267</number>
    <date>29-12-2006</date>
    <name>
      <name>
        <from>01-05-2000</from>
        <to>01-01-2003</to>
        <text>foo</text>
      </name>
      <name>
        <from>01-01-2003</from>
        <to>29-12-2006</to>
        <text>bzz</text>
      </name>
    </name>
    <information>
      <deltagertype>person</deltagertype>
      <leader>John Smith</leader>
      <status>Active</status>
    </information>
    <role>Responsible</role>
    </deltager>
    <deltager>
      <number>4000134982</number>
      <date>05-12-2007</date>
      <name>
        <name>
          <from>07-07-2007</from>
          <to>05-12-2007</to>
          <text>bar</text>
        </name>
      </name>
      <information>
        <deltagertype>person</deltagertype>
        <leader>Wolfgang Smith</leader>
        <status>Active</status>
      </information>
      <role>Responsible</role>
    </deltager>
    ...
  </deltagere>
</report>
```

As you can see the name attribute can hold multiple names. I have managed to import the XML into my database, but only with the first name attribute.
The code I have written so far is:

```
DECLARE @XmlFile XML

SELECT @XmlFile = BulkColumn
FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\input.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x;

INSERT INTO dbo.deltagere(number, dato, nameFrom, nameTo, nameText, deltagertype, leader, deltagerStatus, deltagerRole)
SELECT
  number = deltagere.value('(number)[1]', 'bigint'),
  dato = deltagere.value('(date)[1]', 'varchar(10)'),
  nameFrom = deltagere.value('(name/name/from)[1]', 'varchar(10)'),
  nameTo = deltagere.value('(name/name/to)[1]', 'varchar(10)'),
  nameText = deltagere.value('(name/name/text)[1]', 'varchar(30)'),
  deltagertype = deltagere.value('(information/deltagertype)[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
  leader = deltagere.value('(information/leader)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
  deltagerStatus = deltagere.value('(information/status)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
  deltagerRole = deltagere.value('(role)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
  @XmlFile.nodes('/report/deltagere/deltager') AS XTbl(deltagere);
```

Which gives me this output:

```
| number     | dato       | nameFrom   | nameTo     | nameText | deltagertype | ...
| 142555267  | 29-12-2006 | 01-05-2000 | 01-01-2003 | foo      | person       | ...
| 4000134982 | 05-12-2007 | 07-07-2007 | 05-12-2007 | bar      | person       | ...
```

I would like to have a row for each name/name. So something like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| number     | dato       | nameFrom   | nameTo     | nameText | deltagertype | ...
| 142555267  | 29-12-2006 | 01-05-2000 | 01-01-2003 | foo      | person       | ...
| 142555267  | 29-12-2006 | 01-01-2003 | 29-12-2006 | bzz      | person       | ...
| 4000134982 | 05-12-2007 | 07-07-2007 | 05-12-2007 | bar      | person       | ...
```

and so on.

I'm really lost in how to do this. So I hope any of you have any ideas on how to modify my code to allow this or maybe an different approach on the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - you need to do a second `.nodes()` call to enumerate all `<name>` subnodes:

```
SELECT
    number = deltagere.value('(number)[1]', 'bigint'),
    dato = deltagere.value('(date)[1]', 'varchar(10)'),
    -- NEW NEW NEW - read from `XC` pseudo columns to get 1-n names
    nameFrom = XC.value('(from)[1]', 'varchar(10)'),
    nameTo = XC.value('(to)[1]', 'varchar(10)'),
    nameText = XC.value('(text)[1]', 'varchar(30)'),
    deltagertype = deltagere.value('(information/deltagertype)[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
    leader = deltagere.value('(information/leader)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    deltagerStatus = deltagere.value('(information/status)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    deltagerRole = deltagere.value('(role)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    @XmlFile.nodes('/report/deltagere/deltager') AS XTbl(deltagere)
CROSS APPLY
    deltagere.nodes('name/name') AS XT2(XC)
```

Comment: Maybe you can help me out with another question. 
What if some of the nodes doesn't have any <name> nodes. Then 0 rows is inserted. Any way to just write NULL in the name columns if that is the case?